# vertically text for the label in the header column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less, css-tables

I am trying to make a table with Vertical Text just on the header table.

[image]

Here is my CSS code:

```
table th.user {
  .rotate(90deg);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 190px;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Here is the demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GnveJ

As you can see it works partially.
I would like to have the columns (the cells of the column where there are the name) which width fits exactly the contents (about 50 px); the same as the pic I attached to this question.
Any idea what is the best way to make the css code or js code for this purpose?

Requirement:
I am using less and jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the username in a `span`, rotate that, and set a `width` on the cells. If you rotate the cells, the table will render its size before it rotates the text.

```
table th.user span{
  display:block;
  .rotate(90deg);
  padding: 190px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
.user, tbody td {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/xswoc)

Comment: He is using LESS. Change `.rotate()` (a mixin) to `-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);` (with all the vendor prefixes) for plain CSS.

Comment: It rotates but it does not fit the width :(

Comment: +1 it works pretty fine..just I would like to center the label. thanks.