# Vertically text in Internet Explorer 8/9 inside a table

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, less

To the help of the user "bookcasey",
I did a table having the header labels vertically oriented.

[image]

It works in the following browser (Firefox, Google chrome, safari) except Internet Explorer 8/9.

With IE 8/9 it works but the width of the column is too large. 
Any hints how to resize the width of the columns?

---

The code is to this link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DjFcE

The question is related to this one [vertically text for the label in the header column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963748/vertically-text-for-the-label-in-the-header-column/12963886#comment17578096_12963886)

Comment: I wonder about the usability of vertical, English text

Comment: It works in IE9 if you remove the `-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);`. Otherwise it applies both the `-ms-transform` and the `transform` and you end up with upside-down text. ;)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas , mrk , The vertical text is very effective for a table with a lot of columns. Anyway since it works very fine for ff, chrome, safary.. I would like to have it also for IE 8-9

Comment: It maybe effective for saving horizontal room, but it's very hard to read. And it works in IE9 with the fix I mentioned above.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas it work in IE9 but what about the width... to me it looks too large. It will be possible to resize it as in the picture attacehd to this question? thanks

Comment: @js999 I find the picture confusing. What you should upload is either a single image depicting the problem, or at most two images for showcasing both the problem and the desired solution.

Comment: Ugh, that demo is not very readable... Here, use this: http://jsfiddle.net/h93Tg/3/

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Comment: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/real-text-rotation-with-css

Comment: this [related answer][1] works for your issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272799/vertical-rotated-text-in-html-table